# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_nav_menu()

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I am getting this error which

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_nav_menu()
>   in
>   /home/stageidg/public_html/idg/wp-content/themes/idg-child/secondmenu.php:2
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   /home/stageidg/public_html/idg/wp-content/themes/idg-child/secondmenu.php
>   on line 2

line 2 in the php file is this:

```
wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Services', 'theme_location'=>'services' ) );
```

and its being called by this jquery code:

```
$.ajax(
{
url: "http://example.com/idg/wp-content/themes/idg-child/secondmenu.php", // path to your PHP file
dataType:"html",
success: function(data)
{

   $(data).appendTo(inner_overlay); // load-into-div is the ID of the DIV where you load the <select>

} // success
}); // ajax
```

any idea? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `secondmenu.php` is called separately, not in a WordPress context, so it doesn't know anything about the WordPress functions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, like @fuxia says, include **wp-load.php** to get the WordPress API (wp_nav_menu included) to use. In your case:

```
<?php

include '../../../../wp-load.php';
```

This way you did is not wrong but there are better ways to use AJAX in WordPress:

https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Be happy, my friend!

Comment: this worked! well i had to do another way but it did lead me to the answer which was... define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); // Don't load theme support functionality
require( '../../../wp-load.php' ); thank you for the prompt response!